# Pandas DateFormatter mangles months

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas to plot some data. I have used `df.resample` to group the data by week.  Using the default axis formatting, the ticks show up correctly (i.e. from Jan 2014 to Jan 2015).

I want to reformat them to only display months.  However, when I render the x-axis ticks with a custom DateFormatter, the tick labels show up as April-June.  Why is this happening?  How do I get these dates to show up correctly?

```
              foo      bar     baz
date                              
2014-01-05   3595    60050   63645
2014-01-12   5752   103638  109390
2014-01-19   5424    97629  103053
2014-01-26   5621    96979  102600
2014-02-02   4926    95415  100341
2014-02-09   6124    97690  103814
2014-02-16   8211   104957  113168
    ...       ...     ...     ...

resampled_df = df.resample('w', how='sum', axis=0)
ax = resampled_df.plot(title=str(graph_title),lw=2,colormap='nipy_spectral',marker='.',markersize=10,use_index=True)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b'))
```

[image: my broken plot]